# Redirect to Index if user is not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, devise

I have this in my application_controller.rb:

```
private

  def require_user_signed_in
    unless user_signed_in?

      # If the user came from a page, we can send them back.  Otherwise, send
      # them to the root path.
      if request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
        fallback_redirect = :back
      elsif defined?(root_path)
        fallback_redirect = root_path
      else
        fallback_redirect = "/"
      end

      redirect_to fallback_redirect, flash: {error: "You must be signed in to view this page."}
    end
  end
```

And I added this in my application.html.erb (the layout for the page) right after the start of the body:

```
<% require_user_signed_in %>
```

**My question is** how why is it not working? I am getting an undefined local variable or method error. Am I not calling the method correctly? Do I have to define something somewhere for it to be usable in the layout erb?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to `application_helper.rb` instead or make it a helper method, if you want to keep it in `application_controller.rb`, remove `private` and add the following line

```
helper_method :require_user_signed_in
```

Hope that helps!